# Python + Matplotlib -> NoneType error with twinx

Tags: python, matplotlib

I think I'm missing something in the workflow of matplotlib...  I'm trying to create a figure of custom size, add some stuff, then add a second axis:

```
#temp graph
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.cla()
plt.clf()
plt.close()
df = r

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot()

#r is a dataframe filled with a bunch of data

myplot = r[r.index<=100]["TOTAL DATA"].apply(lambda x:x/1000).plot(kind='bar')
ax2 = ax.twinx()
plt.show()
```

This gives me the following error:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        13 
>        14 
>   ---> 15 ax2 = ax.twinx()
>        16 
>        17 plt.show()
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'twinx'

Any thoughts?   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `fig.add_subplot()` returns `nothing` (**None**), so you will not have a new Axes. You must use the `plt.subplots()` function, it returns a Figure object and an Axes object

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

plt.cla()
plt.clf()
plt.close()
r = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,1),columns=['TOTAL DATA'])

fig, ax= plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 6))

myplot = r[r.index<=100]["TOTAL DATA"].apply(lambda x:x/1000).plot(kind='bar')
ax2 = ax.twinx()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

simple issue.  the ax variable isn't the axes in scope.  myplot is.  myplot.twinx() works.

Comment: Actually `ax` is not an axes at all.

Comment: The problem in the question has nothing to do with axes scope. If no further argument is given, `DataFrame.plot()` would simply plot to the last axes it finds or create a new one. As detailed in the other answers, the problem is rather that `ax` is `None`, because no argument has been given to `add_subplot()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking more in the direction of the attempt in the question, the only problem in the code is that `ax = fig.add_subplot()` returns `None` **because it has no argument given**.

The usual way is to call `ax = fig.add_subplot(111)` or any other (set of) argument(s) that actually creates a subplot. [See documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot).

Therefore the code from the question works fine, if that argument is given.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
r = pd.DataFrame({"TOTAL DATA" : [1000,2000,3000]})

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

myplot = r[r.index<=100]["TOTAL DATA"].apply(lambda x:x/1000).plot(kind='bar')
ax2 = ax.twinx()
plt.show()
```